# Enterprise Library recent version or related

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enterprise-library

I'm looking for an application block for data access, logging and exception management like Enterprise Library but i saw than the lastest version of MEL are a little obsolete (2013)

Did someone know another framework more updated and active support?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if SO is the right place for this question.

Comment: Ent Lib DAB has pretty much been obsoleted by ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) like Entity Framework, or even not-really-orms like Dapper.

Comment: You could check https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore, it is MEL ported for .NET Core and .NET Standard 2.0